# module not found - PYTHON

Tags: python

When I use this command

```
import sys
sys.path
```

It returns

```
['', 'C:\\Users\\Keshav Reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Keshav Reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Keshav Reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Keshav Reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32', 'C:\\Users\\Keshav Reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Keshav Reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Keshav Reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Keshav Reddy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

When I used pip to install pywinauto,

```
C:\Users\Keshav Reddy\pip install pywinauto
```

It returns,

```
C:\Users\Keshav Reddy\pip install pyautogui
```

It returns,

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyautogui in c:\users\keshav reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymsgbox in c:\users\keshav reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): PyTweening>=1.0.1 in c:\users\keshav reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in c:\users\keshav reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyscreeze in c:\users\keshav reddy\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from pyautogui)
```

But when I import it,

```
C:\Users\Keshav Reddy\python

Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pyautogui'
```

Not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you try typing the following into your terminal:

```
pip freeze
```

and see if in that list of modules you have the module you are looking for.  If you don't see the module, try typing

```
sudo pip install XYZ
```

where xyz is the module you are interested in installing.

Comment: The reason I suggested the above is that if you in fact have the module, but Python doesn't see it, you might have a PATH issues linking the modules to your python.

Comment: There was a similar issue here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/279866/python-module-not-found-after-manual-install)